# Encoding error in Reputation tab in user profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, encoding

The following question:

[What's the difference between "Chain of responsibility" and "Strategy" patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5039024/whats-the-difference-between-chain-of-responsibility-and-strategy-patterns)

appears in my *Reputation* tab as:

`What&#39;s the difference between &ldquo;Chain of responsibility&rdquo; and &ldquo;Strategy&rdquo; patterns?`

The same happens with other questions like:

[What's the name of this design pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013502/whats-the-name-of-this-design-pattern) (`What&#39;s the name of this design pattern?`)

It seems like questions there aren't being HTML decoded.

Comment: Gotta love razor; if you get it wrong, the default is that you get double-encoded - which is **much**  preferable to an xss bork from forgetting to encode it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed in source; will probably be deployed at some point over the next day.

Comment: Just to know... what exactly did you write to fix it? (in code)

Comment: @Oscar - I changed some wrong code to some right code ;p (it related to `string` vs `IHtmlString` if you really want to know)